# HTML/CSS - Fixed Backgrounds while scroll

Tags: html, css, background, parallax.js

Any idea or explanation how they did the backgrounds of this site?
http://upcircuit.org/
Basically, a fixed background is the trick here.
But there are multiple backgrounds and I am trying to solve the tricks of this site :))
I tried scanning the page source but I have no idea how they did this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have panels that are the size of the window.  Then what they are doing is setting a background image for each panel and setting its `background-attachment: fixed` so that it stays positioned relative to the window, not the div it is in.

I set up the fundamentals for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc822/

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;  // Sets the html and body width and height 
    height: 100%; // to the width and height of the window.
    margin: 0;
}
.panel{
    width: 100%;  // Sets each panel to the width and height
    height: 100%; // of the body (which is set to the window)

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;  //Sets background fixed in window
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then you just need to specify a `background-image` for each individual panel.

Pretty sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: oh yeah. I found it out for myself about now xD Thanks for confirming the idea I have in mind :D It's the exact same thing I'm am doing right now :D

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? Have you tried to use

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parallax effect, which emulates a 3D space by having your foreground and background move at different speeds. It looks like images are perhaps swapped out and fixed at certain scroll spots. You'll need to use a little javascript, but it is not too difficult a trick to pull off:

Here's a library to help:

http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/?utm_medium=App.net&utm_source=PourOver

Here's another neat site that does some neat things with parallax and scrolling: https://www.google.com/nexus/5/

Comment: woah!I guess this was the one I was looking for :D But I'm not entirely sure since the site i have given uses css (or I dunno if there's a javascript in that part) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is parallax effect. Here are some tutorials:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-scrolling-parallax-website/

http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/

http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

Here are some examples for inspiration:

http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html